# How to use asp:placeholder inside a repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, placeholder

I have a HTML table that is built with a repeater. Sometimes the table has 5 rows, sometimes it has 8 rows.

It was easy to add the header rows.

`<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="additionalHeaderColumns" />`

In code behind I added controls (htmlheadercells) to the contentholder:

```
Dim tableHeaderCell As New TableHeaderCell()
tableHeaderCell.Text = "Test"
additionalHeaderColumns.Controls.Add(tableHeaderCell)
```

When I try to do the same in the databound event for each row I get an errormessage that tells that its not possible to put asp:PlaceHolder inside the row. it expects tablecells.

Anybody have a solution how to expand number of columns in a repeater?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem as "add columns to the table depending on some data":

```
<asp:Repeater ID="outerRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>fixedHeaderCell</td>
                <td>fixedHeaderCell2</td>
                <asp:Repeater ID="innerColumnRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# someFreakySourceFromYourPageOrOuterRepeater %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <td>dynHeaderCell</td>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>fixedContentCell</td>
            <td>fixedContentCell2</td>
            <asp:Repeater ID="innerColumnRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# someFreakySourceFromYourPageOrOuterRepeater %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>dynContentCell</td>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

look further for nested repeater, there is a lot of content here.